# "Attempted to Read or write protected memory" error reading AutoCad databases in parallel

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, autocad

I am getting "Attempted to Read or write protected memory" when I try to perform some parallel operations. I am reading AutoCad Databases into to memory to do some data mining. I can do this with a regular `for` loop but not with a `Parallel.ForEach`. Any ideas?

```
Parallel.ForEach(_Files, (currentFile) =>
{
    var _File = currentFile;
    using (Database _Database = new Database(false, true))
    {
        _Database.ReadDwgFile(_File, FileOpenMode.OpenForReadAndAllShare, false, null);           
        _Database.CloseInput(true);
        // Do Stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by [Miiir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33765868/4838205), AutoCAD does not support multi-threading.

The workaround could be with AutoCAD Console (accoreconsole.exe). If you have an external app (.exe), use it to call several instances of the console, where you can NETLOAD a .NET plugin that will do your data mining. As each console instance is a separate app, there is no multi-thread.

I did some testing with AutoCAD Console on a 8-core machine. As you can see, the overall process takes less time (when compared to running in sequence). Check this PDF I wrote: [Using .NET Programming to Create New Possibilities with the AutoCAD® Core Console](http://aucache.autodesk.com/au2012/sessionsFiles/3338/3323/handout_3338_CP3338-Handout.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting the PDF. I tried to find the class outline at http://au.autodesk.com/au-online/overview but that site is completely useless for finding anything from the past. Try searching for "cp3338" or "core console".

Answer (score 2):

AutoCAD does not support multi-threading or parallel processes.