# How to suppress errors during AutoCAD script execution

Tags: scripting, autocad, error-suppression

I am running an autocad script against a library of 40,000 DWG files.   All the script does is open each drawing and verify that the correct drawing number is on the drawing.   This is for quality control checking.

My problem is some of the drawings have minor inconsequential errors that I wish to ignore.  These errors cause dialog boxes to appear which halt the execution of the script and require a manual intervention.   With 40,000 drawings this is getting old fast.   I have attached examples of the types of inconsequential errors that are being encountered.

My question is how to suppress all errors and force AutoCAD to load the drawing without regard to errors?

[image: error1]

[image: error2]

[image: error3]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead calling **acad.exe** for your script, call **accoreconsole.exe**, which is the best for this scenarios (easier to avoid manual interactions).

Here is a quick .BAT that you can use with AutoCAD Console (and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33766332/4838205) some additional information)

```
FOR %%f IN (C:\dwg_folder\*.dwg) DO "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2016\accoreconsole.exe" /i "%%f"  /product ACAD /s "C:\folder\yourScript.scr" /l en-US
```

As an alternative, you can consider [Design Automation API](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2), which have a AutoCAD running on the cloud for batch processing.

Comment: I should have mentioned using AutoCad 2012.   No core console.  But would work if we had newer version.

Comment: added a paragraph with a webservice option. Don't believe you can avoid all message boxes while automating AutoCAD tasks. Under Options you can hide some, not all of them.